# reference multiple listboxes with string in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listbox

I just decided to make some codes in Visual Basic 2010 instead of using VBA for excel. but im having some trouble to manage some loops. In VBA, when i need to add/Read a item in a listbox i used a loop with `me.controls("Listbox" & i).additem` code.

```
for i=0 to 2
me.controls("listbox" & i).additem
next
```

But here in visual basic this does not work, the function `.controls` dont acept strings to link objects. Anyone have some idea of add/read multiple objects without type manually the code for each object?

Comment: `Me.Controls.Find("listbox" & i)(0).additem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the value of the control names (or type) to get the listboxes. It's less efficient, since you have to go through all the controls in the form, but it's not too time consuming.

```
For Each ctl As Control In Controls
  For i As Integer = 0 To 2
    If ctl.Name = "ListBox" & i Then CType(ctl, ListBox).Items.Add("asdf")
    Next i
  Next ctl
```